# What are the best open source bots available for NLHE (2 player and multiplayer)

Tags: texas-hold-em, nlhe, poker-tools, software, soft-question

Seeing bots that play as well as Libratus and Deepstack is pretty fascinating but, aren't there any good open source implementations available?

I found a couple of reimplementations on GitHub that seem to have bugs.

What are the best open source poker players available right now?

Comment: I don't think you can get a winning poker bot for free. Wouldn't make sense. It is also illegal to let a bot play on a client.